# How can I Change a number sequence on Two tables that Have Same numbers in several rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with multiple rows:

```
Table A
(TYPE - Num)
DA - 1
DA - 2
DA - 3
DA - 4
DA - 5
DB - 1
DB - 2
.
.
.
```

```
Table B
(TYPE - Num - NumLine)
DA - 1 - 1
DA - 1 - 2
DA - 1 - 3
DA - 1 - 4
DA - 2 - 1
DA - 2 - 2
DA - 2 - 3
DA - 2 - 4
DA - 3 - 1
DA - 3 - 2
DA - 4 - 1
DA - 5 - 1
DB - 1 - 1
DB - 1 - 2
DB - 1 - 3
DB - 2 - 1
.
.
.
```

And I want the NUM to start from a specific number for DA and a different number for DB: Example: I want DA to start from 12 and DB to start from 20, and I want this change to apply to both tables, on the corresponding row.

```
Table A
(TYPE - Num)
DA - 12
DA - 13
DA - 14
DA - 15
DA - 16
DB - 20
DB - 21
.
.
.
```

```
Table B
(TYPE - Num - NumLine)
DA - 12 - 1
DA - 12 - 2
DA - 12 - 3
DA - 12 - 4
DA - 13 - 1
DA - 13 - 2
DA - 13 - 3
DA - 13 - 4
DA - 14 - 1
DA - 14 - 2
DA - 15 - 1
DA - 16 - 1
DB - 20 - 1
DB - 20 - 2
DB - 20 - 3
DB - 21 - 1
.
.
.
```

How can I do this? I want to apply this for a lot of rows.

Comment: It would help if your narrative and sample data agreed (or if they do, what are `LA` and `MB` which aren't present in your sample data at all?)

Comment: I edited the post. I meant DA and DB (instead of LA and MB)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply an Updatable CTE that will Change Grouped Numbering and Apply it to two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69673116/how-to-apply-an-updatable-cte-that-will-change-grouped-numbering-and-apply-it-to) You asked this already, don't post multiple times